# How to get Column names of a table Using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anybody help me regarding this... My code is below :

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT id,zone,latlng FROM `rl_zones`');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    // here i need column names i.e id,zone,latlng.
    // i want to display those column names....
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IN pdo use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("DESCRIBE rl_zones");
$STH->execute();
$table_fields = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r($table_fields);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
$column_name = array_keys($row);
print_r($column_name);
```

you will get what you need;

Comment: Thanks bro. Working Fine. :)